# Configure routes in node.js

Tags: node.js, routes

I'm stuck on it since Friday, please.. somebody help me!!!

I have this route in my app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('login', {
        user: req.user
    });
});
```

He is rendering the layout inside the views folder, which is inside the server folder.

I have this configuration in my app.js:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

It's not working put:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '../public');
```

Because it's searching like this:

```
"app/server../public"
```

and i need this:

```
"app/public"
```

Please, if someone know fix this, please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use the `path` module to join paths.

```
var path = require('path');
var uri = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
```

Comment: can you explain better?.. i'm already require the path module to bower_components

Comment: The `path` module is native to node. So require it at the start of the your app.js and do `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));` instead of concatenating them yourself.